# How to send a different '$event' as an argument?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to send the "$event" that '(onLocationSelected)' returns as an argument in the 'searchInputChanged' function on (change). Any idea on how to do this, or an alternative? Thanks[image: ![I'm trying to do something like this]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKst5.png)

Note: 'onAutoComplete' is part of the 'matGoogleMapsAutocomplete' dependencie.

```
            <input matInput 
                matGoogleMapsAutocomplete 
                country="PR" 
                placeholder="Search for location" type="address"
                formControlName="firstCtrl"
                (onAutocompleteSelected)="onAutocompleteSelected($event)"
                (onLocationSelected)="onLocationSelected($event)"
                (change)="searchInputChanged(onLocationSelected $event)"
                required>
```

Answer (score 2):

in your onAutocompleteSelected method, save the value of your event to a property in your component, then have searchInputChanged access that property.

in your component....

```
onAutocompleteSelected(event) {
    // do whatever
    this.autocompleteEvent = event
}

searchInputChanged() {
    // use this.autocompleteEvent instead of passing a parameter
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your suggestion. Both, "(onAutocompleteSelected) and (onLocationSelected)" are part of the matGoogleMapsAutocomplete dependencie. I am trying to do something similar to this:

***(onLocationSelected)="onLocationSelected(send this ==> $event)"
(change)="searchInputChanged(over here)"**